# Issue with JavaScript while programing a Analog Clock

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to make a simple analog clock and while I tried to program the hands of the clock, they don't move. 
I've only marked up with CSS the seconds hand to test, but it isn't working.

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>

        body{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            background-color:#E9E9E9;
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
            overflow:hidden;
            text-align:center;
            position:absolute;
        }

        #clock {
            margin:0 auto;
            top:100px;
            width:600px;
            height:600px;
            background-color:white;
            box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #A4A4A4;
            border-radius:300px;
            text-align:center;
        }

        #sec{
            position:relative;
            width:300px;
            height:10px;
            top:300px;
            left:300px;
            background-color:black;
            transform-origin:top left;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="clock">
        <div id="hour"></div>
        <div id="min"></div>
        <div id="sec"></div>
    </div>

    <script>

    window.addEventListener('load',(function init(){clock();}));

function clock(){
    var d, hour, min, sec;
        d = new Date;
        hour = d.getHours();
        min = d.getMinutes();
        sec = d.getSeconds();

    setAttr('min',min*6);
    setAttr('sec',sec*6);

    setInterval(clock, 1000);

}

function setAttr(id,val){
    var a = 'rotate(' + val + 'deg)';
    document.getElementById(id).style.transform = a;
}

function setAttr(id,val){
    var a = 'rotate(' + val + 'deg)';
    document.getElementById(id).style.transform = a;
}


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I post the Fiddle if somebody can help me.
https://jsfiddle.net/ubm06q32/

Comment: Couple of bugs that jump out... in your clock() - d.getHours()... what is d? setTimout() only calls the method once, try setInterval() which calls repeatedly.  Then, run in chrome, use F12 tools and set breakpoints in the script to see what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things that are preventing this from working.

The first is that your code is never executing.  You're attaching an event to the window's `load` event, but that event can only have one thing attached to it.  The way you have your jsFiddle set up, the jsFiddle load event handler is clobbering (overwriting) it, so it's never getting called.  If you change the jsFiddle options to `No wrap - in <head>`, it will solve that problem.

A better solution still is to use a safe, portable solution like jQuery, which handles the complexities involved in managing multiple page load scripts.

Once that's been handled, there was a typo in your code: using `d` instead of `date` (once the code is actually running, you'll see that on the console).

Fixed jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kjs7esbs/1/

Answer (score 1):

Its a typo make d to date

```
function clock(){
     var date, hour, min, sec;
     date = new Date;
     hour = date.getHours();
     min = date.getMinutes();
     sec = date.getSeconds();

     setAttr('min',min*6);
     setAttr('sec',sec*6);

     setTimeout(clock, 1000);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things I noticed in your fiddle:

1. what is 'd'? needs to be changed to 'date'
2. what is 's'? needs to be changed to an integer
3. change setTimeout to setInterval

Updated code:

```
function clock(){
    var date, hour, min, sec;
        date = new Date;
        hour = date.getHours();
        min = date.getMinutes();
        sec = date.getSeconds();

    setAttr('min',min*6);
    setAttr('sec',sec*6);

    setInterval(clock, 1000);

}
```

Updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ubm06q32/13/

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you need, this is the working version of the analog clock:

```js
var date, hourPos, minPos, secPos;
    
function clock(){   
    date = new Date;
    
    secPos = date.getSeconds() * (360 / 60);
    minPos = date.getMinutes() * (360 / 60) + secPos / 60;
    hourPos = date.getHours() % 12 * (360 / 12) + minPos / 60 + secPos / 3600;
    
    setAttr('hour', hourPos - 90);
    setAttr('min',  minPos - 90);
    setAttr('sec', secPos - 90);
}

function setAttr(id,val){
    var a = 'rotate(' + val + 'deg)';
    document.getElementById(id).style.transform = a;
}

setInterval(clock, 1000 / 60);
```

```css
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color:#E9E9E9;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
}

#clock {
    margin:0 auto;
    top:100px;
    width:600px;
    height:600px;
    background-color:white;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #A4A4A4;
    border-radius:300px;
    text-align:center;
}

#sec{
    position:relative;
    width:250px;
    height:3px;
    top:300px;
    left:300px;
    background-color:black;
    transform-origin:top left;
}

#hour{
    position:relative;
    width:150px;
    height:3px;
    top:300px;
    left:300px;
    background-color:yellow;
    transform-origin:top left;
}

#min{
    position:relative;
    width:230px;
    height:3px;
    top:300px;
    left:300px;
    background-color:blue;
    transform-origin:top left;
}

#sec{
    position:relative;
    width:280px;
    height:3px;
    top:300px;
    left:300px;
    background-color:black;
    transform-origin:top left;
}
```

```html
<div id="clock">
    <div id="hour"></div>
    <div id="min"></div>
    <div id="sec"></div>
</div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ubm06q32/18/

Comment: Once I saw the issue I fixed it and it worked, now I have my working analog clock :D thank you for effort!